# Delete entries from SSIS package execution report in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2012, ssms-2012

I've deployed SSIS packages into SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and tried to execute project.
But, It failed to run due to some configuration errors.

In order to resolve issues, I changed configurations multiple times and executed SSIS project in SSMS.
Now, issues resolved and job is running successfully.

However, execution information report shows lot of failure entries and I'd like to delete them.

[image]

Experts, could you please help with how to delete those entries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under 'Integration Services Catalogs', right click SSISDB - Properties, under 'Operations Log', 'Retention Period', by default installation, it is 365 days. You may adjust it. SQL Server will delete for you. It will delete all projects log, not just this project.

The other way is to delete records in database SSISDB tables. Not recommended.

Comment: Thank you Wendy. Could you please provide few reasons why I shouldn't be going with latter approach (deleting from SSISDB tables)? There are multiple projects run on SSMS and use SSISDB. I don't want to change logs of those.

Comment: Usually we should not delete records directly from system databases tables, such as master db, msdb.

Comment: @Wendy that doesn't really answer the first comment, why shouldn't we touch the system tables.